# How to prevent empty category to list content of sub categories?

Tags: categories

I have a category structure like following:

```
A
->B
  ->C
D
```

(B is sub category of A and C is sub category of B)

I have content only for category "C" and if I open Category "B" the content of category "C" is displayed. How can I prevent this? I want to display "No Posts" if I open Category "B".

Comment: Can you post some of your code? It will help get to the answer

Comment: @MridulAggarwal his code doesn't matter, he has asked general question

Comment: Then i understood it wrong. My Bad

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the context here is filtering out posts from category C when viewing the category B posts archive, you could accomplish this by using the `query_posts` keyword `category__in` (which **does not** include posts from child categories) instead of `cat` (which **does** include posts from child categories). Just add it in `archive.php` or `category.php` depending on what's appropriate for you theme.

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array(
    'category__in' => get_query_var('cat')
));
query_posts( $args );
```